# Pegar dados de um Objeto PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou listando dos dados de uma query que fiz com o seguinte código:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
 ->join('transportes', 'users.id', '=', 'transportes.user_id')
 ->join('empresas', 'transportes.id', '=', 'empresas.transporte_id')
 ->join('motoristas', 'transportes.id', '=', 'motoristas.transporte_id')
 ->join('caminhoes', 'motoristas.id', '=', 'caminhoes.motorista_id')
 ->select('caminhoes.cavalo', 'caminhoes.carreta', 'transportes.data_registro')
 ->whereBetween('transportes.data_registro',['2017-01-01 03:02:46','2018-03-12 11:59:25'])
 ->get();
```

E está saindo o seguinte resultado:

> object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#206 (1) { ["items":protected]=>
>   array(15) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#213 (3) { ["cavalo"]=> string(7)
>   "AAA-221" ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-196" ["data_registro"]=>
>   string(19) "2018-03-06 22:41:07" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#209 (3) {
>   ["cavalo"]=> string(7) "AAA-221" ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-196"
>   ["data_registro"]=> string(19) "2018-03-06 22:41:07" } [2]=>
>   object(stdClass)#212 (3) { ["cavalo"]=> string(7) "AAA-221"
>   ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-196" ["data_registro"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-03-06 22:41:07" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#215 (3) { ["cavalo"]=>
>   string(7) "AAA-489" ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-213"
>   ["data_registro"]=> string(19) "2018-02-27 01:52:54" } [4]=>
>   object(stdClass)#208 (3) { ["cavalo"]=> string(7) "AAA-489"
>   ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-213" ["data_registro"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-02-27 01:52:54" } [5]=> object(stdClass)#207 (3) { ["cavalo"]=>
>   string(7) "AAA-388" ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-309"
>   ["data_registro"]=> string(19) "2018-02-27 01:52:54" } [6]=>
>   object(stdClass)#210 (3) { ["cavalo"]=> string(7) "AAA-388"
>   ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-309" ["data_registro"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-02-27 01:52:54" } [7]=> object(stdClass)#216 (3) { ["cavalo"]=>
>   string(7) "AAA-448" ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-209"
>   ["data_registro"]=> string(19) "2018-02-27 01:52:54" } [8]=>
>   object(stdClass)#217 (3) { ["cavalo"]=> string(7) "AAA-448"
>   ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-209" ["data_registro"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-02-27 01:52:54" } [9]=> object(stdClass)#218 (3) { ["cavalo"]=>
>   string(7) "AAA-401" ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-271"
>   ["data_registro"]=> string(19) "2018-02-27 01:52:54" } [10]=>
>   object(stdClass)#219 (3) { ["cavalo"]=> string(7) "AAA-401"
>   ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-271" ["data_registro"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-02-27 01:52:54" } [11]=> object(stdClass)#220 (3) { ["cavalo"]=>
>   string(7) "AAA-187" ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-422"
>   ["data_registro"]=> string(19) "2018-02-27 01:52:54" } [12]=>
>   object(stdClass)#221 (3) { ["cavalo"]=> string(7) "AAA-187"
>   ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-422" ["data_registro"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-02-27 01:52:54" } [13]=> object(stdClass)#222 (3) { ["cavalo"]=>
>   string(7) "AAA-276" ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-438"
>   ["data_registro"]=> string(19) "2017-12-18 20:35:44" } [14]=>
>   object(stdClass)#223 (3) { ["cavalo"]=> string(7) "AAA-276"
>   ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-438" ["data_registro"]=> string(19)
>   "2017-12-18 20:35:44" } } }

eu gostaria de poder pegar os dados separados. Exemplo: pegar só a coluna 'cavalos' e listar?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver, apenas transformei meu objeto em um array com a função `toArray()`

da seguinte forma `$array = $users->toArray();`

assim lista da seguinte forma:

> array(15) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#213 (3) { ["cavalo"]=> string(7)
>   "AAA-221" ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-196" ["data_registro"]=>
>   string(19) "2018-03-06 22:41:07" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#209 (3) {
>   ["cavalo"]=> string(7) "AAA-221" ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-196"
>   ["data_registro"]=> string(19) "2018-03-06 22:41:07" } [2]=>
>   object(stdClass)#212 (3) { ["cavalo"]=> string(7) "AAA-221"
>   ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-196" ["data_registro"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-03-06 22:41:07" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#215 (3) { ["cavalo"]=>
>   string(7) "AAA-489" ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-213"
>   ["data_registro"]=> string(19) "2018-02-27 01:52:54" } [4]=>
>   object(stdClass)#208 (3) { ["cavalo"]=> string(7) "AAA-489"
>   ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-213" ["data_registro"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-02-27 01:52:54" } [5]=> object(stdClass)#207 (3) { ["cavalo"]=>
>   string(7) "AAA-388" ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-309"
>   ["data_registro"]=> string(19) "2018-02-27 01:52:54" } [6]=>
>   object(stdClass)#210 (3) { ["cavalo"]=> string(7) "AAA-388"
>   ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-309" ["data_registro"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-02-27 01:52:54" } [7]=> object(stdClass)#216 (3) { ["cavalo"]=>
>   string(7) "AAA-448" ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-209"
>   ["data_registro"]=> string(19) "2018-02-27 01:52:54" } [8]=>
>   object(stdClass)#217 (3) { ["cavalo"]=> string(7) "AAA-448"
>   ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-209" ["data_registro"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-02-27 01:52:54" } [9]=> object(stdClass)#218 (3) { ["cavalo"]=>
>   string(7) "AAA-401" ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-271"
>   ["data_registro"]=> string(19) "2018-02-27 01:52:54" } [10]=>
>   object(stdClass)#219 (3) { ["cavalo"]=> string(7) "AAA-401"
>   ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-271" ["data_registro"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-02-27 01:52:54" } [11]=> object(stdClass)#220 (3) { ["cavalo"]=>
>   string(7) "AAA-187" ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-422"
>   ["data_registro"]=> string(19) "2018-02-27 01:52:54" } [12]=>
>   object(stdClass)#221 (3) { ["cavalo"]=> string(7) "AAA-187"
>   ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-422" ["data_registro"]=> string(19)
>   "2018-02-27 01:52:54" } [13]=> object(stdClass)#222 (3) { ["cavalo"]=>
>   string(7) "AAA-276" ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-438"
>   ["data_registro"]=> string(19) "2017-12-18 20:35:44" } [14]=>
>   object(stdClass)#223 (3) { ["cavalo"]=> string(7) "AAA-276"
>   ["carreta"]=> string(7) "BBB-438" ["data_registro"]=> string(19)
>   "2017-12-18 20:35:44" } }

com isso eu consigo pegar os dados.. ex.:

```
echo $array[0]->cavalo
```

resultado:

> string(7) "AAA-221"

Comment: Eu removeria do select 'caminhoes.carreta', 'transportes.data_registro' se você não está usando e o join em empresas.

Comment: Essa solução é ruim, traz dados da tabela que você não precisa (ou que pelo menos você não relatou a utilidade). No `select` só traga aquilo que realmente vai utilizar.

Comment: Beleza, Obrigado! Estou fazendo os ajustes :D

Comment: Eu preciso de todos esses dados, eu fiz de acordo com a tabela que pediram para eu gerar.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

O método `get()` retorna uma `Collection` que é um objeto com diversos métodos úteis para aplicar sobre a coleção de dados retornados.

Para pegar uma única coluna de todos os itens da sua coleção pode utilizar o método `pluck('nome_da_coluna')` , por exemplo `$users->puck('cavalo')` retornará uma `Collection` com os valores da coluna cavalo:

```
#items: array:15 [▼
    0 => "AAA-221"
    1 => "AAA-221"
    2 => "AAA-221"
    ...
  ]
```

A documentação do método `pluck` e de outros métodos podem ser encontradas aqui: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-pluck

Você também pode iterar sobre uma coleção normalmente:

```
foreach($users as $user){
    echo $user->cavalo . PHP_EOL;
    echo $user->carreta . PHP_EOL;
}
```